# Не могу подключиться к mysql из функции, кто может помочь?

Tags: php, mysqli, функции

Сайт выдает ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined variable: bd Warning: mysqli_query() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Подключение к бд:

```
$bd = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name) OR DIE ('Не удалось установить соединение');
```

Функция:

```
function upload_file($file) {
    if ($file['name'] == '') {
        echo 'Файл не выбран!';
        return;
    }

    if (copy($file['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$file['name'])) {
        //header('Location: /index.php');
        //exit;
        echo ' :: Файл успешно загружен!';  
    } else {
        echo ' :: При загрузке файла произошла ошибка';
    }   

    $source = 'img/'.$file['name'];
    $query_url = "INSERT INTO images (url) VALUES ('img/".$source."')";
    $sql_s = mysqli_query($bd, $query_url);
    if ($sql_s) {
        echo 'Ссылка на файл успешно сохранена в базу!';
    } else {
        echo '<br>Ошибка при сохранении ссылки в базу! :(';
    }
}
```

P.S. За пределами функции все нормально, но мне нужно именно в функции понять что да как.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: А вы в эту функцию $bd передали? Думаю, проблема в видимости переменных в функции и за ее пределами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри функции нет переменной $bd. Что бы пробросить ее снаружи, нужно в начале функции написать

```
global $bd;
```

А лучше передавать ее вторым параметром.